# Characteristic Polynomial of $4×4$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in M_{4}(\mathbb{F})$ where $a_{ij}=1, 1\leq i,j \leq 4$.
Other than solving $det(xI-A)$, is there an easy way to get the characteristic polynomial of $A$?
Is there a way to determine if $A$ can be diagonalized without calculating $p_{A}(x)$?

Comment: If you find a polynomial $p$ with $p(A)=0$, then the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $p$. I hope it helps.

Comment: Changed the letter `x` with symbol `×` in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find four linearly independent eigenvectors by inspection.  For instance 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$$ is an eigenvector.

Also $$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ is an eigenvector.

Can you find two more?

You can then identify eigenvalues and their multiplicities and use that information to find the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: doesnt $\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix}$ span the kernel?

Comment: and more than that, how can I know how many eigenvectors there are? there might be 4 and there might be 1.

Comment: Symmetric matrices always have 4 linearly independent eigenvectors

Answer (score 0):

this is a rank one matrix $uu^\top, u = (1,1,1,1)^\top$ has eigenvalues $\{u^\top u, 0,0,0\} = \{4, 0,0,0\}.$  therefore the char equation $$det(xI - A ) = x^3(x-4).$$